# Printing filename before printing lines

Tags: bash, awk

Am using the following bash function to print specific ranges lines from files.

```
print-lines ()
  {
    na=$1
    nb=$2
    dir=$3

    find "$dir" \( -name \*.org -o -name \*.texi \)  \
      -exec awk -v a="$na" -v b="$nb"                \
             'FNR >= a && FNR <= b {print}' {} +
  }
```

I have two files like this

```
foo:
a
b
c
d
e 

bar:
1
2
3
4
5
```

Let the command be `print-lines 2 4`. I want the result to be

```
==> foo <==

b
c
d

==> bar <==

2
3
4
```

Comment: Should the filename be printed if the file has less than `$na` lines?

Comment: No, only the matches.  Have changed the code a bit.  It avoids overrunning the command line buffer.  Imagine if your command line buffer holds 32KB, and your for loop returns 40KB of text. That last 8KB will be dropped right off your for loop and you'll never know it.

Answer (score 3):

If the filename should only be printed if the file has at least `$na` lines:

```bsh
find . -name '*.csv' -exec awk -v a="$na" -v b="$nb" '
    FNR == a {print "==>", FILENAME, "<=="}
    a <= FNR && FNR <= b
' {} +
```

If the filename should be printed for every file regardless of its contents, GNU awk is handy

```bsh
find . -name '*.csv' -exec gawk -v a="$na" -v b="$nb" '
    BEGINFILE {print "==>", FILENAME, "<=="}
    a <= FNR && FNR <= b
' {} +
```

Comment: Have modified the code a little bit using your suggestion.  But I cannot get any output right now.

Comment: Am wondering whether it would be better to use `sed` this way `sed -n "$1,${2}p" "$file"`

Comment: You have `while read -d $'\0'` but you're not using `-print0` for find. `xargs -0` would be better than a shell while-read loop, but why not use `-exec` in find?

Comment: In this case, sed is worse than awk: you need to invoke one sed per file, while awk can accept multiple files. IMO sed is more awkward to inject new lines of text into the stream.

Comment: Much appreciative of your analysis of sed.  Regarding `-exec`,  would the resulting command avoid overrunning the command line buffer, if there are many file matches?

Comment: re -exec: yes, check the man page.

Comment: Nice answer. Since the OP is apparently talking about thousands of files of unknown size, it'd be more efficient if your awk supports `nextfile` (e.g. GNU awk) to do `FNR==1{f=0} FNR==a{print "==>", FILENAME, "<=="; f=1} f{print; if (FNR==b) nextfile}'` or similar.

Comment: This would exit when reaching line number defined by `b`.

Comment: Yes, I am using gnu awk.

Comment: Have added red colour to the filename.

Comment: Have used `tput` to add colour to the file name.  Have also added the possibility of using `escape characters`.  But I need to have a single `print` command in `awk` that allows the colour to be set either with `tput` or `escape characters`.

Comment: That's beyond the scope of your question: I'd recommend you ask a new one.

Comment: @Pietru regarding [This would exit when reaching line number defined by b](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656188/printing-filename-before-printing-lines#comment1234493_656195) - no, it'd move on to read the next file when reaching line number defined by b thereby no wasting time reading the rest of the lines from the current file that it won't print.

Comment: Yes, it read the next file.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the header printed by `head` and `tail`, you can make one of them print it. To get lines from A to B inclusive, counting from 1, first tell `tail` to start at line A (`+A`) then tell head to retain the first B-A+1 lines, plus one for the header line.

```
tail -n "+$na" -v -- "$filename" | head -n $((nb - na + 2))
```

Called from find, with an empty line after each file (almost as `head` or `tail` would do — the code here adds an empty line at the very end):

```
find … -exec sh -c 'tail -n "+$1" -v -- "$0" | head -n $(($2 - $1 + 2)); echo' {} "$1" "$2" \;
```

Comment: Head and tail work well, but I would like to print line ranges with awk.  I just want to print the filename before the call to awk on each file.

Answer (score 0):

You may let `find` do that printing by `printf`-statements. Note that in `-exec` `+` is no more possible like this, you will have to use the case-by-case call of `awk`.

```
print-lines () {
    na=$1
    nb=$2
    dir=$3

    find "$dir" \( -name \*.org -o -name \*.texi \)  \
    -printf '==> %p <==\n\n' \
    -exec awk -v a="$na" -v b="$nb" 'FNR >= a && FNR <= b' '{}' \; \
    -printf '\n'    
  }
```

May be a bit less performant than using `awk`-only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Using **GNU sed** we use the -s option to give multiple files to sed and be treated separately.

```
find "$dir" -type f \
  \( -name "*.texi" -o -name "*.org" \) \
  -exec sed -sne "
    ${na}{x;s/.*/==>/p;F;s//<==/p;x;}
    $na,${nb}p
" {} +;
```

---

Python in conjunction with the pathlib module to traverse hierarchy and itertools to slice files

```
python3 -c 'import pathlib, itertools, sys
na,nb,dir = sys.argv[1:]
p = pathlib.Path(dir)
for q in p.glob("**/*"):
  if q.suffix in [".texi",".org"] and q.is_file():
    with open(q.name) as f:
      L = [l.rstrip("\n") for l in itertools.islice(f, int(na)-1, int(nb))]
    if len(L) > 0:
      print("==>",q.name,"<==")
      print(*L,sep="\n")
' 2 4 .
```